# php mail() wont send email

Tags: php, email

I'm a beginning php coder (really beginner) and I need to make a postcard-sending script but it wont send my emails.

```
<?php
$to_name = $_REQUEST['to_name'];
$to_email = $_REQUEST['to_email'];
$subject = 'teszt';

$msg = 'proba';

mail($to_mail, $subject, $msg, 'From:' . 'teszt@valami.hu');
?>  

<label for='to_name''>Címzett neve:</label>
<input type='text' name='to_name' id='to_name' class='gbi' size='30'>
<label for='to_email''>Címzett email cime:</label>
<input type='text' name='to_email' id='to_email' class='gbi' size='30'>

<label for='name''>Az ön neve:</label>
<input type='text' name='name' id='name' class='gbi' size='30'>

<label for='email''>Az ön email cime:</label>
<input type='text' name='email' id='email' class='gbi' size='30'>

<label for='text''>Üzenet:</label>
<textarea name='text' id='text' class='pct' ></textarea>
<br>
<input type='submit' >
```

Yes it is it a form :)

So the point is I made 4 images, every for images have a different submit button, so when they click on it a for pops up for the image.

I tried everything to send out the mails and no luck.

Any advice?

Comment: sorry not postcars postcard :)

Comment: and really sorry about my typeing, its almost sunrise and i ahvent slept a bit

Comment: Are you using POST to submit the form data?

Comment: Does your [`mail()` command return true or false](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)? You should check return values, they can be useful. Check your server's mail logs (`mailq` may do the job), was an email accepted for delivery? Was the delivery attempted? Did delivery fail for any good reasons?

Comment: Most importantly: do you have a mail server?

Comment: Note that all your `<label for='blah''>` includes an extra `'` single quote. Probably unrelated, but it might cause problems elsewhere.

Comment: And a further note: if this form is on a publicly accessible website, it is almost an [open relay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mail_relay). Anyone can use your program to mail anyone else on the internet. If someone receives messages from your system without their consent, you may be added to [Realtime Blackhole Lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNSBL#Terminology) and emails from your IP or netblock (your ISP) will be dropped by thousands of mail servers across the internet. Be careful. :)

Comment: One of these probably answers your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+email

Comment: What operating system is your php running from? Windows requires a few configuration changes to get mail functions to work.

Answer (score 1):

Please submit all of your code including `<form..>` tag.

Also can you replace your php code to this and try again:

```
<?php 
   if (!empty($_REQUEST['to_email'])) {
      $to_name = $_REQUEST['to_name'];
      $to_email = $_REQUEST['to_email'];
      $subject = 'teszt';
      $msg = 'proba';

      mail($to_mail, $subject, $msg );
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest forgoing mail() all together, and using [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/). It's not hard to setup, even for someone just starting.